# responsiveVoice not working after page load, click needed

Tags: javascript, php, html, onmouseover, responsivevoice

I sometimes need to use refresh of my website. The problem is that the responsiveVoice voice function is always interrupted and does not resume until the page is anywhere clicked. Minimized example (no sound after load, after clicking the sound will be played):

```
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
</head>
      
<body>
<a href="" onmouseover="{responsiveVoice.speak('text to speach');}">text to read - move the mouse over me</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Any idea how to enable responsiveVoice after refresh WITHOUT REAL CLICK, some pre-defined code, any trick etc.?

Comment: This is by design, to prevent sites from auto playing sounds (and annyoing users) the user must have interacted with the page previously before audio will be played